Squared distance computation in PyTorch - Avoid for loop
I have a code where a 2D grid of size (20, 20) when flattened (400) needs to have distance computed from all other indices on the 2D grid. Currently, I am using a for loop to store it.
# best locations of indices existing on 2D grid-
best_loc.shape
# torch.Size([1024, 2])

# Specify 2D grid size-
m = 20
n = 20

locs = [np.array([i, j]) for i in range(m) for j in range(n)]
locations = torch.LongTensor(np.array(locs))

locations.shape
# torch.Size([400, 2])

def get_distance_squares(best_loc):
    '''
    Compute squared distances between 'best_loc' and 'locations'
    '''
    best_loc = best_loc.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(locations).float()
    best_distance_squares = torch.sum(torch.pow(locations.float() - best_loc, 2), 1)
    return best_distance_squares
     
bmu_distance_squares = list()

for loc in bmu_loc:
    bmu_distance_squares.append(get_distance_squares(loc))
best_distance_squares = torch.stack(best_distance_squares)

best_distance_squares.shape
# torch.Size([1024, 400])

How can I avoid the for loop for getting "bmu_distance_squares" which is a pairwise squared distance matrix?

did you mean the function get_bmu_distance_squares is get_distance_squares?

Why is the removal of for loop relevant here? It is unlikely to have any affect on performance. You could pre-allocate memory for results, but as loop is to input values to function, there should be minuscule overhead.

corrected the code

The most straight-forward answer is already pointed out by @Mercury, but I also want to point out another way to compute what you want, as @Mercury's answer will suffer from numerical error created by the sqrt from the torch.cdist, using native pytorch oprator:
bmu_distance_squares = (best_loc.unsqueeze(-2) - locations.unsqueeze(-3)).pow(2).sum(-1)


You can simply use torch.cdist.
bmu_distance_squares = torch.cdist(best_loc, locations) ** 2


You could try to treat the mxn grid as a graph with m*n nodes, and making use of torch-cluster, use any neighbor search like torch_cluster.radius, which can be pretty efficient when used with CUDA.
